# how to highlight the circle area in iOS google map?

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am very new to iOS map, and learning google map. I am trying to create a view as followings:

1. dark the google map
2. highlight the position on the map

[image]

First I created a google mapview with a black background, then set the optical value:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.mapView setAlpha:0.7];
GMSCircle *geoFenceCircle = [[GMSCircle alloc] init];
geoFenceCircle.radius = radius;
geoFenceCircle.position = position; 
geoFenceCircle.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.7];
geoFenceCircle.map = self.mapView;
```

This allows me to create a dark map view, but the highlight will be dark too.

[image]

This seems google map should offers such functionality, but I couldn't find it. I really appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: You have to colour the "outside" of the circle, not what's within it. You need to create a polygon covering the whole globe, with a hole in it which is the highlight.

Comment: Thank you. This sounds better, will give it a try.

Comment: Did someone manage to do this? Im looking for a solution also.